# Electron app - how to disable/hide the windows in the taskbar in full-screen mode

Tags: windows, modal-dialog, electron, kiosk

I've been struggling with this for a while and still didn't find any good solution. 
I am developing a Windows full-screen (kiosk) app and I need to have a modal window for a password to exit the app. I did the modal window and the functionality, but the problem is now that when the modal appears, the main window exits the full-screen and shows the Windows (OS) task-bar with both windows (main and modal).

One way to do fix this is force the app to become the Windows shell instead of Explorer. 
I tried to do it by changing the reg. key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` to my app exe file, but it doesn't work. When I restart, it still opens the explorer shell.

I also tried to edit the same Shell key in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\...`, but that one requires you to run **as Admin**, which is another trouble cause I could not make Electron write that reg. key as admin.

**Note**: the code I use to open the main window is:

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    fullscreen: true,
    frame: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    kiosk: true,
    skipTaskbar: true,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      nodeIntegration: false,
      devTools: true
     }
  })
```

So, does anyone please have any idea about how to:
 - Either make the main app stay full-screen all the time, or...
- Make the "Shell" registry key be properly enabled and keep the value of the app.

Thank you very much for everyone's time and help!

Comment: Important update. 
I had an idea and just earlier I installed the project on an Ubuntu machine **exactly as it is on Windows** and when I ran it, everything WORKED PERFECTLY!?!?
The main window remains full-screen, the modal window sits nicely on top of the main one and nothing is visible on the docker bar at any time.
More that that, when you click out of the modal window **it doesn't disappear**, as it does in the Windows env.
I guess Microsoft shows again its ability to break things or make them harder at all costs... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can include the code like this:

```
win.removeMenu();
```

or

```
win.setMenu(null);
```

where,
win is the instance of the created browser window forexample,

```
let win = new BrowserWindow(options:{
        width: 1200,
        height: 800,
        icon: 'path/to/icon'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

add the `autoHideMenuBar: true` key-value pair to your win definition:

```js
win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1250,
    height: 660,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    icon: getAssetPath('icon.png'),
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the already given answers are correct. You have to set the window as always on top with a maximum possible level, combined with fullscreen to achieve this.

```js
mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, 'screen-saver');
```

The `screen-saver` level will make sure that the taskbar won't appear in-front of the the fullscreen window. Unfortunately you can't set the level in BrowserWindow configuration. Read more about this in [the documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winsetalwaysontopflag-level-relativelevel).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. `mainWindow.setFullScreen(true)`